# How can I send the response.body out of request module function?

Tags: node.js, express, httprequest, httpresponse

I started by creating a `return` statement in the request function (I have linked a picture) and then `console.log` it outside of the `function` but that didn't work out.

**My server code**

```js
var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'url': 'http://localhost:8080/ES_Part1/api/user/getUser',
  'headers': {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  form: {
      'username': username,
      'password': password
  }
};

requestToApi(options, function(error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log("Send form data to remote api and to return the user from Spring")
  console.log(response.body);
  return response.body
});

var fromapi = response.body;

res.end();
```

**Example:** [image: 1]

Comment: which version of `node` are you using?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) Could you insert your code as code instead of image?

Comment: version 12.14.1

Comment: the url in options is the path to my remote rest api that im getting the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

‍ If you want to get `respose.body` outside the handler, than you can use this code below :

```js
// an example get function
app.get('/users', async(req, res) => {
  var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'url': 'http://localhost:8080/ES_Part1/api/user/getUser',
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    form: {
        'username': username,
        'password': password
    }
  };

  const result = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    requestToApi(options, function(error, response) {
      if (error) return reject(error);
      return resolve(JSON.parse(response.body));
    });
  })

  // make sure, to use async in your function
  // because we're using await here
  var fromapi = await result;
  // It's working here
  console.log(fromapi);

  res.end();
})
```

That code above , only an example that you can use to read `response.body`. If you want to handle the error from that code above, you can use like this code below:

```js
try {
    // make sure, to use async in your function
    // because we're using await here
    var fromapi = await result;
    // It's working here
    console.log(fromapi);
  } catch(ex) {
    // print error response
    console.log(ex.message);
}
```

I hope it's can help you .

Comment: Thanks, and if it's really help you, please give me upvote. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a `Promise`-based approach here rather than the callback-style that you're using for `requestToApi`. If you're using the `request` package, there is a `Promise`-based version available.

Alternative solution would be to create a `promise` yourself, like such:

```js
var requestToApiAsPromise = (options) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    requestToApi(options, (error, response) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error)
        return
      }
      resolve(response.body)
    })
  })
}
```

Then you can use this method in your middleware:

```js
app.post("/checkUser", (req, res) => {
  async function process() {
    try {
      var username = req.body.username
      var password = req.body.password
      var options = {...}

      var response = await requestToApiAsPromise(options)
      // response => response.body

      // do whatever

      res.end()
    } catch (error) {
      next(error)
    }
  }
  process()
})
```

This method uses `async/await` so that it lets you write your code as if you were doing things synchronously, so it's making it easier to make asynchronous calls and have them "wait" before the next line gets executed.

Comment: ok but how can i export the response.body out of any functions?

Comment: @JohnDinos I just showed you how - use `async/await` with a `promise` to "wait" for your database call to finish and save it in the `response` variable. Then on next line, do whatever you'd like with this variable... It's an asynchronous call, so you will either have to do everything inside of the callback for your `requestToApi` function or do something like I did above.